# Querying with apollo-link-state gives the error "Field <name> doesn't exist on type 'Query'"

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I'm totally new to both Apollo and GraphQL. I'm following along with [this apollo-link-state-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RvRcnD8wHY), and am hitting a stumbling block.

I have set up my link with a `currentGame` property default.

```
const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache: stateCache,
  defaults: {
    currentGame: {
      __typename: 'currentGame',
      teamAScore: 0
    }
  }
})
```

I'm using it in my client.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  stateCache,
  link: stateLink,
  ...
})
```

I'm defining a GraphQL query like this:

```
const getCurrentGame = gql`
  query {
    currentGame @client {
      teamAScore
    }
  }
`
```

I am connecting it to my component's props.

```
export default compose(
  graphql(getCurrentGame, {
    props: ({ data: { currentGame }}) => ({
      currentGame
    })
  })
)
```

This generates an error in the console.

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Field 'currentGame' doesn't exist on type 'Query', Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
```

I've gone over my code and haven't been able to spot what is surely a typo or simple mistake. How can I debug this error message, or what does it suggest the problem is?

---

**Update:** I have tried adding a resolver as suggested by Tal Z, but am still receiving the same error message.

```
const stateCache = new InMemoryCache()
const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache: stateCache,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      currentGame: () => {
        return {}
      }
    }
  },
  defaults: defaultState
})
```

For what it's worth, most of the few example repositories I've found have queries for fields that do not have resolvers defined. For example, [this queries for todo list items](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/blob/master/examples/todo/src/components/TodoList.js#L7), but [the only resolver defined is for a mutation](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/blob/master/examples/todo/src/resolvers.js#L10).

Comment: Have you tried using `fetchPolicy: 'network-only'` as one of the query options?

Comment: I hadn't seen that option, I just tried it with network-only and cache-only and it had no effect.

Comment: Can you add your apolloClient config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out... this breaks:

`import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'`

This works:

`import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'`

I have no idea what the difference is.

Comment: I haven't tried `apollo-boost` yet. Your experience could save me some frustration while trying it. Thanks!

Comment: No, thank you for trying, and I hadn't heard seen fetchPolicy yet so that was cool to learn too!